# Set property value while selecting from list of class objects

Tags: c#, list, linq

Am trying to set value(day value to "Sunday") while selecting from list, like below in method 'getData', is there a way I can set it without really changing class object property 'day' value? I just want it set to 'Sunday' while reading, like 'Sunday' as 'day'.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleAppForChecking
{
    public class test
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tests = new List<test>()
            {
                new test { firstName = "Mike", lastName = "Toss", age = 20, day = "Monday" },
                new test { firstName = "Peter", lastName = "Page", age = 30, day = "Tuesday" },
                new test { firstName = "Stacy", lastName = "Page", age = 27, day = "Wednesday" }
            };

            getData(tests);
            GetDate(tests);
        }

        public static void getData(List<test> _data)
        {
            var _data1 = _data.Where(w => w.firstName == "Stacy")
                              .Select(o => new 
                                           { 
                                             o.firstName, 
                                             o.lastName, 
                                             day = o.day = "Sunday",
                                             o.age 
                                           })
                              .ToList();
            foreach(var d in _data1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
        }

        public static void GetDate(List<test> _data1)
        {
            foreach (var d in _data1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you just want `day = "Sunday"` ? In this case no need to assign `o.day` else the source object's property is definitively changed ...

Comment: @OlivierRogier-I could set day to Sunday, but I dont want the actual class object property 'day' value to be altered. I just want to select 'Sunday' as 'day'. Class is being used in multiple places.

Comment: @.DeSon Therefore do what I wrote. Remove `o.day =`. Run the new code and see that it works now: the query shows "Sunday" for all new "cloned" objects from the source collection created using LINQ while the source is not changed ... Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @OlivierRogier-Ah! Right. Dont know how I couldnt get that. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierRogier - Can we change field names while selecting from list? Like firstName as 'FN' from above

Comment: Yes: just do what you done with day => `new { MyFirstName = o.firstName, MyLastName = o.lastName, MyDay = "Sunday", MyAge = o.age })` • [Linq 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) • [Linq 2](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/linq) • [Deferred Execution of LINQ Query](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution) • [LINQ (MSDocs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score -1):

```
_data.Where(w => w.firstName == "Stacy")
                              .Select(o=> {o.day = "Sunday"; return c;})
                              .ToList();
```